# Surfaces not being illuminated

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, light

I have problem with rendering in cycles render in [this building](http://www54.zippyshare.com/v/3023371/file.html).
I placed lots of different lamps and increased the amount of emission in the lamp, but it didn't work.
If I render, it shows this:

[image: Render result]

Comment: Your file link is broken

Comment: Sory tis is work http://www54.zippyshare.com/v/3023371/file.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the walls etc. only have a *glossy* shader with 0 roughness. This means light will be reflected specularly, without being scattered. In other words, **every surface is acting as a perfect mirror**.

See [How do you make a lamp light up glossy surfaces?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/3594/599) for a more detailed explanation of why this is a problem.

To fix this, try using a diffuse shader instead:

[image]

Though eventually you'll want to set up a mix of different shaders (probably a bit of both diffuse and glossy) with textures, etc.