# Lamp is not illuminating

Tags: light

I'm not sure why my lamp isn't working.  Here are the screenshots:

[image: screenshot of solid view]

[image: screenshot of material view]

[image]

Comment: Your lamps are working well. The problem is the plane (on which the joystick lies) has the Glossy node Roughness value set to 0, which means it reflects the World (which has a very dark color) in 100%. The joystick has a Glass material, which reflects a very dark World color as well. Try to set the World color to something brighter or set up the HDRI image for Environment Texture.

Comment: See http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/3594/599

Comment: Thanks @Gonzou I never knew that roughness on the texture played a role in light reflection.

Comment: Thanks @gandalf3 that was a great explanation of this issue in the link you provided

Comment: @PaulGonet OMG. I searched for 1 hour why my scene is dark with portals. It was because the world-color was set to a very dark color. In all this tutorials no one is talking about the world-color. Thank you very very much!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a couple of problems:

1. You are trying a glass object and a glossy black object (the plane). Highly reflective objects need something to reflect! Create some environment and you'll see that your lights work.
2. Your objects are quite large! So the lights also need to be a bit more more powerful

Here's your scene with a white hemisphere and your lights a bit brighter:
[image]

To leave the environment out of the rendered image turn off the visibility for the camera

[image]

Blend file to play with:
[image]

---

EDIT:

if what you are after is some glow in the dark effect you might want to add a plane with an emitter shader as a light source under the object and forget about the lights on the scene altogether.

[image]

[image]

Or have no other emitters in the scene than the object generating its own luminescence:

[image]

and why not? another blend:

[image]

Comment: Those are good points.  I did sort of get carried away with the size of the object and once I fixed the roughness of the glossy plane it was apparent I had to increase the lamp strength.  However, I am trying to create the effect of luminescence in the dark.  The hemisphere worked well, but is there a way to render the image without the background showing, i.e. transparent?

Comment: As @cegaton suggested you can turn off the visibility of the camera (in Properties window go to the Object menu-->Ray Visibility panel-->uncheck the Camera checkbox). If you want to render with the transparent background check the Transparent checkbox (Properties window-->Render menu-->Film panel-->check the Transparent checkbox). More details here: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1303/can-blender-render-pngs-with-the-background-transparent

Comment: @lakerice updated answer...

Comment: Sorry for the late reply; I've been trying out all those files and still trying to tweak it and experiment...but awesome setups and I am definitely getting closer to what I want.